# Mootools link hover and color change

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mootools, mouseover, mootools-events

I am using the mousenter demo from mootools. I put it on my site trying to affect the links so when someone hovers over them the link fades into another color. The problem I am having is that the mootools code is only set up to handle one ID! Since I am using it for a navigation, I have multiple IDs that I want to change.  How can I affect all of them?  I know I should use an array but I'm not that good with Javascript in order to code it properly. Please help!

The URL is [www.portfoliobyart.com/h20](http://www.portfoliobyart.com/h20)

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at your site.  In `demo.js`, if you change this line

```
$('link').set('opacity', 0.5).addEvents({
```

to this:

```
$$('.nav a div').set('opacity', 0.5).addEvents({
```

you will achieve the same effect for every item in your nav menu.

You should read up on [MooTools selectors](http://www.consideropen.com/blog/2008/08/30-days-of-mootools-12-tutorials-day-2-selectors/) for more about this.  Selectors are a very powerful tool.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! This was a great help. Up and working now.o will def. Check out the mootools selector page for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

the code below will take each of the nav link elements and add the mouseenter and mouseout events.

```
//selects all nav elements
$$('.nav a div').each(function(el){
    //this is the interior of the function that will run on each el
    //store the original bg color
    var color = el.getStyle('backgroundColor');

    //now add the mouseenter and leave events w/ the morphs
    el.set('opacity', 0.5).addEvents({
        mouseenter: function(){
        // This morphes the opacity and backgroundColor
            this.morph({
                'opacity': 1,
                'background-color': '#000000'
            });
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
        // Morphes back to the original style
            this.morph({
                opacity: 0.5,
                backgroundColor: color
            });
        }
    });
});
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Using .each() is certainly better because it only does one loop.  If you do it zombats way (no offense!) it'll loop over the array when you set the opacity, and then loop it again when you add the events, and again if you chain more stuff.